# Ubuntu 16.04 wifi not appearing in networks available

Tags: wireless

I am new to the ubuntu operating system and for some reason after installing it I do not see any wireless connections. My system uses:

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)

So far I have tried

1.Turn off the secure boot

2.Remove bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source

3.Re-install bcmwl-kernel-source and the kernel header:
sudo apt-get install linux-generic bcmwl-kernel-source

4.Reboot
sudo reboot

After I reboot, nothing changes at all.

When I run: sudo lshw -C network

This is what I get for the network controller:

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Limited
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b0500000-b0507fff
```

I believe the network controller driver is not installed properly, therefore not working but I am not sure.

Can anyone suggest anything to try and get this to work.

Thank you!

Comment: Please post output of `sudo modprobe wl` to your question.

Comment: When i run that I get modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Required key not available

Comment: The Secure Boot is enabled.

Comment: My problem was the secure boot was enabled. Thank you @Pilot6